# Facing issue while creating new project with xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

I am not able to create a new project on my new Mac mini machine, it does not show me the location to create the project. But I am able to run other project that has already been created on other machines.

OS version on my machine is - OS X Yosemite version: 10.10.4

and I have two XCode version i.e : 6.4, 6.1

[image]

Comment: do you want to use your machine as a GIT .....

Comment: No, I simply want to create it on my machine.

Comment: Then deselect the check box shown above.... and right on the project file and select find file

Comment: That check box is not clickable and it is the process of creating project so file is not created yet then how can I select it?

Comment: That check box meaning was your going to use your machine as the git for source control or not

Comment: Okay, so how to deselect it if it is not enable? is there any setting in preference?

Comment: check whether MY Mac is changeable or not is there any option to put as empty check

Comment: Yes, there is only one option "Add to new server"

Comment: leave as empty and check